# Firefox 2 float issue?

Tags: html, css

I have a site, http://www.denispellerin.ca/ that works fine in almost all browsers except ff2.0 the #content/.entry areas appear UNDER the sidebar, rather then float to the right. I have tried to fix it several times with no luck, can anyone see a reason why it would not be properly floating? I tried messing with the widths and stuff to see if that was the problem, and that didn't fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when a float jumps down like that, it's due to a size mismatch. Fixed-width container, and too much stuff to fit onto the line, so the floats jump down. Could be a border/padding/margin on the float making it too "fat". Or the menu sidebar being too wide.
Quickest way to test is to narrow its width down by 50px or so and see if it snaps into place.